# GLFW in callback function pass more argument then intended

Tags: c++, callback, glfw

I was working with GLFW and his callback function in C++.
What I want to achieve in the callback function is to modify a variable of type of my class `Keyboard`.

The callback function has to be of type `void(* GLFWkeyfun) (GLFWwindow *, int, int, int, int)`

`glfwSetKeyCallback(GLFWwindow *window, GLFWkeyfun cbfun)` doesn't allow me to pass a lambda function that captures a `Keyboard`.

It works with a templated function but it is very cloggy as the `Keyboard` has to be defined at compile time and that doesn't make the code that object oriented.(i.e. if I want to make a new window is not as easy as making a new instance).

I tried to extend `GLFWwindow` so that I could use polymorphism so that I could put a derivative object ,that contains a `Keyboard`, as the first argument of `glfwSetKeyCallback` so that I can get the same object from the first argument of the callback function. But when I extend `GLFWwindow` my IDE tells me "incomplete type is not allowed"

How can I modify my `Keyboard` from within the callback? I really want my design to be as modular as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have researched I little bit more.
I can put the `Keyboard` in `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` and the get it from the callback using `glfwGetWindowUserPointer`.